# CRTP-related compiler error on typedef

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, typedef, crtp

I have rather simple, I imagine, question about [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but I cannot seem to find an answer to it. Probably, because it is so simple, no one thought of asking it. I am new to the concept, so, please don't laugh too hard ;).

Here is the code (it's sort of an attempt to do something similar to STL containers):

```c++
template< typename tT >
struct TBase
{
  typedef tT T;
};

template< typename tTBase >
struct TTraitsBase
{
  typedef typename tTBase::T T;
};

template< typename tTHelpee, typename tTTraits >
struct THelper
{

  typedef typename tTTraits::T T;
  typedef typename tTHelpee::T Th; /* This generates a compiler error:
                                      'T' not being a member of TDerived<tT> */
  T Foo( void )
  {
   return static_cast< tTHelpee* > ( this )->mVal;
  }
};

template< typename tT >
struct TDerived : TBase< tT > , THelper< TDerived< tT > , TTraitsBase< TBase< tT > > >
{
 using TBase< tT >::T;
  T mVal;
};

int main()
{
 TDerived< int >::T lTmp = -1;
 TDerived< int > lObj;

 lObj.mVal = -1;
 std::cout << lObj.Foo() << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Everything compiles if I comment the offending `typedef typename _THelpee::T Th;`. And that what confuses me: if compiler does not like `typedef typename _THelpee::T Th;`, why does it let through `static_cast< _THelpee* > ( this )->mVal`? I assume, it has something to do with not being able to instantiate `THelper` when instantiating `TDerived`, but no clear understanding. Can someone, please, give a brief explanation and/or some references on what is happening here? Thank you.

EDIT: removed '_T' prefix.

Comment: Identifiers starting with an [_ and followed by a capital letter are reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797) for the implementation.

Comment: Do not use underscore-capital for your own identifiers, that's forbidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicitly instantiating a class does not instantiate its member function definitions.  Each member of a class template is instantiated only when used (unless you use explicit instantiation).

The first thing you implicitly instantiate is `TDerived<int>`, on the first line of `main`.  To instantiate that, the compiler looks up the `TDerived` template, sees that there are a couple of dependent base classes, so tries to instantiate those.  `TBase<int>` instantiates with no problem.  But on trying to instantiate `THelper< TDerived<int>, TTraitsBase< TBase<int> > >`, there's an attempt to get a member `TDerived<int>::T`, but `TDerived<int>` is still an incomplete type.

Instantiating `THelper< ... >` also notes that there is a member function `int Foo()`, but does not evaluate the semantics of its definition.

By the time you call `lObj.Foo()` from `main`, which instantiates that `int THelper< ... >::Foo()`, `TDerived<int>` is a complete type, so there's no problem there.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it clearly. I obviously did not appreciate the function instantiating sequence. I did realize that `TDerived` was indeed incomplete, but could figure out why `Foo()` didn't cause any problems in this case. Now it's clear.

Comment: On a side note, is it considered normal to use `TTraits` or possible `TBase` template parameter to `THelper` to get access to those `typedefs` in `TDerived`? Or is there more "standard" way of doing that (reference on the subject would be greatly appreciated)? And thanks again for your earlier explanations.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of problem with the code posted. Since, I couldn't make out the intention, I will list what I found erroneous.

**(1)** Using an **incomplete type**:

```
template< typename _T >
struct TDerived : TBase< _T > , THelper< TDerived< _T > , TTraitsBase< TBase< _T > > >
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ it's incomplete
```

IMO when you are defining the body of `TDerived<_T>`, you should not use the same as a parameter to anything.

**(2) Improper type** definition.

```
using TBase< _T >::T;
```

should be,

```
typedef typename TBase< _T >::T T;
```

Comment: It's okay for a template parameter to be an incomplete type (and that's always the case with CRTP).  But as with all incomplete types, there are restrictions on valid uses of that type.

Comment: Thanks for the input, iammilind. I think, aschepler answered it. I am reluctant to break the rules and enter a discussion, since I am new here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you have a circular dependency in your CRTP (as one would have, by its very nature), but that means that the base template class isn't allowed to *use* any of its parameter class, because that very parameter class isn't defined yet - it's still an incomplete type at the time where `Base<T>` is instantiated.

So, this is OK:

```
template <typename T> struct Base
{
  T * impl;  // incomplete type is OK
};

class Foo : public Base<Foo> { /* ... */ };
```

But this isn't:

```
template <typename T> struct Base
{
  T x; // need to know T, but T depends on Base<T>!
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose you are saying the same thing as aschepler in his answer, with less detail.